# How to save plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm saving a plot in R that I made with ComplexHeatmap. However, when I save it as a PDF, I could see that there are horizontal lines in the annotation bar. I don't have this issue when I save it as a png file but the plot is blurry. How can I save my plot so that it is clear and the lines don't appear?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In R, the resolution of a plot saved as a PDF is related to the size of the PDF page. You can increase the size, and therefore the resolution, by adding to your code this:

```
pdf(width = 32, height = 18 , onefile = T)
```

Followed by the plotting code, and ending with `dev.off()`.